# Return a list with the files that exist in a specific windows location - using SAS EG

Tags: windows, file, directory, find

I am trying to get a list of all the files that exist in a certain folder location in the windows directory. Next steps will be to automate this and to loop through all the sub-folders (012019, 022019, ...) and to send me an email with the results, however I have not resolved the first part yet.

I have tried the below code but it does not return anything.

```
%macro get_filenames(location);
    filename _dir_ "%bquote(&location.)";

    data filenames(keep=memname);
        handle=dopen( '_dir_' );

        if handle > 0 then
            do;
                count=dnum(handle);

                do i=1 to count;
                    memname=dread(handle,i);
                    output filenames;
                end;
            end;

        rc=dclose(handle);
    run;

    filename _dir_ clear;
%mend;

%get_filenames(C:\user\temp);
```

Comment: So does the C:\user\temp directory exist on the machine where SAS is running? Or does it only exist on the machine where Enterprise Guide is running?

Comment: Hi Tom, by changing the path in the last line, I can get a list of the files that exist within Enterprise Guide in a specified folder.  However I am not sure how can I connect this to the machine I am running EG on - this is on Windows and I am using workgroup network directories.

Comment: You will need to ask for local support on how your network is setup.  Perhaps you can just use what Windows calls UNC paths.  Instead of using drive letters you use a server name and share name. Like `\\servername\sharename\...`